# Use AsyncTask or Thread for frequent read/write operations - Android

Tags: android, json, file-io, android-asynctask

I have built an Android app that allows a user to create new levels for a game I am making. The level maker app allows the user to save new levels and preview all levels they have saved. When the user saves a level, my app generates a `JSONObject` that represents that level, then writes the `JSONObject.soString()` value to a local file (either a Shared Preferences file or a plain old .txt file - I don't know which is better yet). When the user wants to preview existing levels, the app reads in all the JSON Strings from my levels file, converts each JSON to a Bitmap (JSON -> ViewGroup -> Bitmap), then displays all the Bitmaps in a `ListView`.

Right now I am using 2 `AsyncTasks`: one for writing and one for reading. I don't know if I could potentially be spawning 5-10 new Threads per minute, though (one for each time the user saves a new level), and I don't know if that would be a bad thing as far as system resources goes.

Here's my question: because I may need to write to my levels file 5-10 times per minute, is it better to start a new `AsyncTask` each time the user saves a new level, or should I just create one background thread and execute `Runnables` on it each time the user saves or previews levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask is controlled internally by a shared (static) [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and a [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). There are such parameters like core pool size and maximum pool size. Since Android 1.6, core pool size is 5, and the maximum pool size is 128. Queue size is 10 tasks.

So, maximum quantity of parallel AsyncTasks is 5, others will be queued. If your save operation is relatively slow, you may encounter situation when AsyncTask got killed by OS and nothing saved. If you need long-running save operation, it is better to use service.

For me, I prefer using background service with my own ThreadPoolExecutor - this gives me some extra control like cancelling tasks. If you don't want to write extra code, you may use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) - it also uses Executor and queues your tasks by itself.